# Can you use http libraries for an https server?

Tags: http, https

I am wondering if you can use a http library for an API and then place that project behind a https server? What is the thinking behind http and https, and how do they work together.

Comment: What's your definition of "an http library"?

Comment: @Clive A library like `httplib` in python or `http` in go/node.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking - I _think_ it's whether having a site that receives secure incoming connections will affect your ability to make server-side secure outgoing connections using an arbitrary http library? The two things aren't related so if that's the question, the answer is just "no"

Comment: @Clive So you can not use nginx for the https front end reverse proxy. Then handle your backend api in http? That is basically what I am asking. I have a api written with http responses, can I just use nginx as a reverse proxy using https?

Comment: Oh right, yeah your question doesn't give any hints that you're talking about proxying. Yep you can do that, it's been covered at length both here and on the internet in general though so don't be too surprised if no one answers this specific question.